# lapply, data wrangling dates, unexpected output

Tags: r, function

I have a dataset (CSV) where one column contains multiple date formats, it can be

```
|birth_date|
------------
|DD/MM/YYYY|
|YYYY-MM-DD|
| YYYY     |
| [BLANK]  |
```

I'm trying to change the dates in "YYYY-MM-DD" format to "DD/MM/YYYY". I've got the following code so far:

```
# Loading in required libraries
library(tidyverse)
source("R/formatDate.R")

# Reading in the Nobel Prize data
data <- read_csv('datasets/data1.csv')

fixed_birthdates <- lapply(data["birth_date"], function(x) formatDate(x))$birth_date
data[["birth_date"]] <- fixed_birthdates
```

formatDate.R:

```
formatDate <- function(x) {
  output <- x
  if (grepl('-', x, fixed = TRUE)) {
    xx <- strsplit(x,'-',TRUE)
    output <- paste(xx[3],xx[2],xx[1],sep="/")
  }
  return(output)
}
```

However every time i run it the value of `fixed_birthdates` is equal to `"c(\"1854\", \"03\", \"15\")/c(\"1839\", \"03\", \"16\")/c(\"1852\", \"08\", \"30\")"`. That variable has 5 elements where as my original dataset has 969. Not sure why this is happening.

The logic I'm trying to implement is simple, however I don't know how to express it in R. Using c# code it would look something like this:

```
string formatDate (string x)
{
    string output = x;
    if (x.Contains("-"))
    {
        string[] xx = x.Split('-');
        output = xx[1]+'/'+xx[2]+'/'+xx[3];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attempt to format via `as.Date` and then overwrite the values that are successfully parsed. Here's a simple example:

```
data <- data.frame(
  birth_date = c("01/01/2001", "2010-03-14", "1982", ""),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
#  birth_date
#1 01/01/2001
#2 2010-03-14
#3       1982
#4

frmtdate <- as.Date(data$birth_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
data$birth_date[!is.na(frmtdate)] <- format(frmtdate[!is.na(frmtdate)], "%d/%m/%Y")
data
#  birth_date
#1 01/01/2001
#2 14/03/2010
#3       1982
#4
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of `strsplit` is a `list`.  We could vectorize instead of looping through each element, but the OP's code can be corrected by extracting the `list` element with `[[`

```
formatDate <- function(x) {
  output <- x
  if (grepl('-', x, fixed = TRUE)) {
    xx <- strsplit(x,'-',TRUE)
    output <- paste(xx[[1]][3],xx[[1]][2],xx[[1]][1],sep="/")
  }
  return(output)
}

data[,"birth_date"] <- sapply(data[,"birth_date"], function(x) formatDate(x))
data[, "birth_date"]
#[1] "01/01/2001" "14/03/2010" "1982"       ""
```

Comment: This is sorta how i expected the solution to be.. but the above code changes all the dates to the first birth_date value (in the correct format)